# Graphically solving system of inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Please check my work:

Jillian is going to college next year and has decided to start working this summer. She makes $20$ dollars an hour working at a farm and $16$ teaching gymnastics. Write $3$ inequalities.

She wants to

1. Make at most $\$ 800$
2. Work more than $10$ hours per week
3. Work less hours as a gymnastics teacher.

If we set $Y$ = gymnastics, $X$ = farm.

Would the following answers fit?

1. $20x + 16y < 800$ (making at most $800).
2. $x + y > 10$ (working more than 10 hours a week).
3. $x > y$ (working more at the farm than the gymastics class).

Graphing these should create an overlap?

Answer (score 1):

At most would include equality as well. Hence the first inequality should be $$20x+16y \le 800.$$